# Armazenar retorno de XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Eu tenho um retorno de um XML que é um loop(pois é único jeito que sei chamar retorno) porem no XML eu tenho dois `det`, `det nItem="1"` e `det nItem="2"` que sao 2 produtos, dentro deles se encontra a tag `cEAN` que é a que eu preciso separadas em variaveis diferentes para poder usar individualmente cada `cEAN`.

A minha chamada

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("C:\\Users\\Expedição\\Videos\\XML\\xml_teste2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()


ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}

for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    print (EAN.split())
```

O XML usado:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe35200811625533000185550010000043291000219014" versao="4.00">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
<CNPJ>33737452000100</CNPJ>
<xNome>GP CAVALCANTE COMERCIO, IMPORTACAO E EXPORTACAO DE PECAS AUT</xNome>
<enderDest>
...
</enderDest>
<indIEDest>1</indIEDest>
<IE>799164503118</IE>
<email>administrativo@ldrautomotive.com.br; suporte@ldrautomotive.c</email>
</dest>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>ET-CAM 01</cProd>
<cEAN/>
<xProd>CAMERA ESTAC MISTA (FURADA + SUP. BORBOLETA)</xProd>
<NCM>85258029</NCM>
<CEST>2106300</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>UNI</uCom>
<qCom>20.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>22.0000</vUnCom>
<vProd>440.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib/>
<uTrib>UNI</uTrib>
<qTrib>20.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>22.0000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
<imposto>
...
</imposto>
</det>
<det nItem="2">
<prod>
<cProd>ET-CAM 02</cProd>
<cEAN>7898622140258</cEAN>
<xProd>CAMERA ESTAC DIANTEIRA</xProd>
<NCM>85258029</NCM>
<CEST>2106300</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>UNI</uCom>
<qCom>10.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>26.9000</vUnCom>
<vProd>269.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898622140258</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>UNI</uTrib>
<qTrib>10.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>26.9000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se quer processar cada valor individualmente, ainda é possível fazer dentro do *loop*. Basta verificar o valor do atributo `nItem` (assumindo que todas as tags `det` possuem este atributo). Algo assim:

```
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    if nItem == '1':
        # cEAN é do nItem 1, fazer o que precisa aqui
    elif nItem == '2':
        # cEAN é do nItem 2, fazer o que precisa aqui
```

Mas se quiser **muito** ter uma variável para cada, você pode buscar individualmente por cada `det`:

```
# busca por <det nItem="1">
det = root.find('.//nfe:det[@nItem="1"]', ns)
if det:
    cean1 = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text

# busca por <det nItem="2">
det = root.find('.//nfe:det[@nItem="2"]', ns)
if det:
    cean2 = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
```

Aí depois você usa cada variável (`cean1` e `cean2`) como bem entender.

Mas se a ideia é processar várias tags de uma vez (com uma quantidade que pode variar), eu ainda acho melhor fazer o *loop* e dentro dele decidir o que fazer (digo isso, claro, sem saber todo o contexto do seu problema).

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda.